# How to test hover actions on react components (in selenium/nightwatchjs)?

Tags: javascript, selenium, reactjs, nightwatch.js

I have very simple react component and this component returns div:

```
return(< div className="item"
onClick={ this._onClick }
onMouseEnter={ this._onMouseEnter }
onMouseLeave={ this._onMouseLeave } >...< /div>);
```

(sorry for weird < and > formatting)

And I use selenium for testing (nightwatchjs framework), so when I write in my test

```
client.click(".item");
```

it works perfectly, I see that _onClick() method is called, but when I try to hover over the element and I write

```
client.moveToElement(".item");
```

or

```
client.moveToElement(".item", 1 ,1);
```

It doesn't work :( , _onMouseEnter() method isn't called.

So - how do you test any hover actions on react components?

Comment: Have you tried to add a delay before moving to the element to ensure that it's not a timing issue?

Comment: yes, I tried pause() before and after moveToElement()

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Could you use `client.mouseButtonUp(0);` and see if its working.

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks for a tip. In my case calling `client.mouseButtonDown(0)` before `client.moveToElement` helped.

Comment: @marcinpl87 did you figure out a solution for this issue?

Comment: @daniula Me, too... seems like focusing on the element was necessary before the hover would work.